# Material Calculator: Dividing the amount of material by unit cost

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a GUI which allows the user to calculate the cost of material used on a 3D print job.

The user should select the printer and the material, then enter the amount of material used (manually taken from the printer software). The GUI should then display the cost of material based on the material and the amount entered by the user.

At the moment, nothing appears below the Cost pf material(£) heading as I can't link these up.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()

app.geometry("500x250")
app.title("AM Materials Cost")
app.maxsize(500,250)
app.minsize(500,250)

# title

Label(text="Additive Manufacturing \\nMaterial Cost Calculator", fg="black", width="20", height="2",     font=("Calibri", 16)).place(x=200, y=10)

# printer text line

Label(text="Select Printer", fg="black", width="20", height="2", font=("Calibri", 11)).place(x=50, y=75)

#material text line
Label(text="Select Material", fg="black", width="20", height="2", font=("Calibri", 11)).place(x=290, y=75)

def clear_text():
text.delete(0, END)

def pick_material(e):
    if printer_combo.get() == "Fortus":
    material_combo.config(value=fortus_materials)
    if printer_combo.get() == "Markforged":
    material_combo.config(value=markforged_materials)  
    if printer_combo.get() == "Polyjet":
    material_combo.config(value=polyjet_materials)

#create list of printers
printers = [
"Fortus",
"Markforged",
"Polyjet"
]

#create list of printers and associated materials
fortus_materials = [
"ASA",
"ABS-ESD7",
"PC-ABS",
"Ultem"
]
markforged_materials = [
"Carbon Fiber",
"Onyx"
]
polyjet_materials = [
"TangoBlack",
"VeroClear",
"VeroWhite",
"Digital ABS",
]

#material price per unit - amend value within " "
asa_ppu = ["0.17"]
absesd7_ppu = ["0.19"]
pc_ppu = ["0.19"]
ultem_ppu= ["0.33"]
carbonfiber_ppu = ["1.00"]
onyx_ppu = ["0.19"]
tangoblack_ppu = ["0.25"]
veroclear_ppu = ["0.28"]
verowhite_ppu = ["0.18"]
digitalabs_ppu = ["0.30"]

#create dropdown box
printer_combo = ttk.Combobox(app, value=printers)
printer_combo.place(x=60, y=110)

#material combobox
material_combo = ttk.Combobox(app, value=[""])
material_combo.place(x=300, y=110)

#material amount text line
Label(text="Enter Material Amount", fg="black", width="20", height="1", font=("Calibri", 11)).place(x=50, y=145)

#material cost text line
Label(text="Cost of Material (£):", fg="black", width="20", height="1", font=("Calibri", 11)).place(x=290, y=145)

#entry box for amount
e = Entry(app,justify="center")
e.place(x=70, y=175)
e.delete(0,'end')

#material cost output
def myClick():
myLabel = Label(app, text='', height="1", font=("Calibri", 20))
myLabel.place(x=340, y=163)

#calculate button
myButton = Button(app, text="Calculate", command=myClick)
myButton.place(x=220, y=170)

#close button
exit_button = Button(app, text="Close", command=app.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=450, y=215)
```

Comment: this code has errors all over it. Mostly from the improper import here `from tkinter import \*`.   It is much better doing this `import tkinter as tk` as the **alias** makes the code clearer.

Comment: Hi, I have removed the 'slashes'....

Comment: There are still indentation issues on some lines.  Did you try to execute your posted code?

Comment: I removed corporate labels before posting here but left in from tkinter import *

Comment: i am waiting for the edit que to clear. there are approximately 30 edits that are needed to be made to the original code in the question....

Comment: Hi @acw1668, yes, visually it looks as it should.